# How to add property to Neo4j database Table that contains entry (DataNucleus)?

Tags: java, neo4j, jdo, datanucleus

I use DataNucleus and JDO. To create the schema for "tables" during the persistence process I use `datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll=true` to tell DataNucleus to auto create schema. Once I have made enty to the Table any attempt to add field to the model results to `org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: NODE[68] has no property with propertyKey="newFieldName"`.

What is the best way to alter or add properties to a Table which already contains entries?

This is the stack trace.

```
2017-12-27 13:46:08.509 [qtp1955990522-68] Query - JDOQL Query : Executing "SELECT FROM com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product WHERE name.equals(value) PARAMETERS String value" ...
2017-12-27 13:46:08.509 [qtp1955990522-68] Native - Retrieving objects of type com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product using Cypher query : START this=node:DN_TYPES(class="com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product") RETURN this
[INFO ] 2017-12-27 13:46:08.537 [qtp1955990522-68] Query - Reading in results for query "SELECT FROM com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product WHERE name.equals(value) PARAMETERS String value" since the connection used is closing/committing
2017-12-27 13:46:08.539 [qtp1955990522-68] Cache - Object with id "com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product:11" not found in Level 1 cache
2017-12-27 13:46:08.540 [qtp1955990522-68] Cache - Object "com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product@74e1d24" (id="com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product:11") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNNYNNNNNNN]")
2017-12-27 13:46:08.567 [qtp1955990522-68] Connection - Managed connection org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@7e678a93 [conn=org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade@18f961ba, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is committing
2017-12-27 13:46:08.567 [qtp1955990522-68] Connection - Managed connection org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@7e678a93 [conn=org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade@18f961ba, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] committed connection
2017-12-27 13:46:08.568 [qtp1955990522-68] Persistence - Disconnecting com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product@74e1d24 from StateManager[pc=com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product@74e1d24, lifecycle=HOLLOW]
2017-12-27 13:46:08.568 [qtp1955990522-68] Cache - Level 1 Cache cleared
2017-12-27 13:46:08.568 [qtp1955990522-68] Persistence - ExecutionContext CLOSED "org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@7464295a"
2017-12-27 13:46:08.568 [qtp1955990522-68] Transaction - Transaction rolling back for ExecutionContext org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@59f25f8e
2017-12-27 13:46:08.568 [qtp1955990522-68] Transaction - Rolling back [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=1608044257-5, enlisted resources=[]]
2017-12-27 13:46:08.568 [qtp1955990522-68] Transaction - Transaction rolled back in 0 ms
2017-12-27 13:46:08.569 [qtp1955990522-68] Persistence - ExecutionContext CLOSED "org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl@59f25f8e"
Dec 27, 2017 1:46:08 PM com.hope.tub.servlets.TuCreateServlet doPost
SEVERE: null
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: NODE[11] has no property with propertyKey="creatorID".
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:479)
at     org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.fieldmanager.FetchFieldManager.fetchLongField(FetchFieldManager.java:157)
at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.replacingLongField(StateManagerImpl.java:1912)
at com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product.dnReplaceField(Product.java)
at com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.model.Product.dnReplaceFields(Product.java)
at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.replaceFields(StateManagerImpl.java:4286)
at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.replaceFields(StateManagerImpl.java:4311)
at org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.Neo4jUtils$1.fetchFields(Neo4jUtils.java:605)
at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.loadFieldValues(StateManagerImpl.java:3719)
at org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.Neo4jUtils.getObjectUsingApplicationIdForDBObject(Neo4jUtils.java:601)
at org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.Neo4jUtils.getObjectForPropertyContainer(Neo4jUtils.java:565)
at org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.query.LazyLoadQueryResult.getResultFromMapRow(LazyLoadQueryResult.java:153)
at org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.query.LazyLoadQueryResult.closingConnection(LazyLoadQueryResult.java:136)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractQueryResult.disconnect(AbstractQueryResult.java:105)
at org.datanucleus.store.neo4j.query.JDOQLQuery.performExecute(JDOQLQuery.java:291)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1966)
at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1855)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:433)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:276)
at com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.services.impl.ProductNeo4jServiceImpl.findByName(ProductNeo4jServiceImpl.java:76)
at com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.services.impl.ProductNeo4jServiceImpl.save(ProductNeo4jServiceImpl.java:90)
at com.hope.tub.neo4j.jdo.services.impl.ProductNeo4jServiceImpl.save(ProductNeo4jServiceImpl.java:24)
at com.hope.tub.access.beans.ProductBean.createProduct(ProductBean.java:135)
at com.hope.tub.servlets.TuCreateServlet.createProduct(TuCreateServlet.java:107)
at com.hope.tub.servlets.TuCreateServlet.doPost(TuCreateServlet.java:57)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
at com.hope.tub.filters.ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenFilter.doFilter(ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenFilter.java:254)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFil[INFO ] 2017-12-27 13:46:08.571 [qtp1955990522-68] / - ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenFilter:DoAfterProcessing
ter(ServletHandler.java:1759)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.__doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.PropertyNotFoundException: NODE[11] has no property with propertyKeyId=29.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:471)
... 50 more
```

Initial Model:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, cacheable = "false", detachable = "true")
public class Product implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8269335445554701873L;

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private String name = null;
...
```

Any attempt to add new property like this below, reproduces the above stack trace.

```
...
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
long id;
@Persistent
private String name = null;
@Persistent
private long creatorID;
...
```

Comment: why not post the stack trace for that exception? because an exception is of zero value without it

Comment: @DN1  I have added stack trace and more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing (non-String) columns are not currently catered for. That is, it assumes that the objects stored in the Neo4j database are consistent with the model used for retrieving them.

That is fixed in GitHub. https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-neo4j/issues/32

Comment: Thanks, @andyjefferson you are doing great.